# Write an extension for the Double type that adds an absoluteValue property

Tags: swift

Does anyone know why the last line outputs -4.0 instead of 4.0?

```
extension Double {
    var absoluteValue: Double {
    if self > 0.0 {
        return self
    }
    else {
        return -1 * self
        }
    }
}

var minusTwo = -2.0
minusTwo.absoluteValue  // 2.0

let minusThree = -3.0
minusThree.absoluteValue    // 3.0

-4.0.absoluteValue  // -4.0
```

Comment: however, (-4.0).absoluteValue  // 4.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s just being parsed as `-(4.0.absoluteValue)`. This works:

```
> (-4.0).absoluteValue
$R2: Double = 4
```

Comment: Also, the Swift 4 Standard Library [`magnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2299224-magnitude) behaves the same as the extension in question. …

(lldb) expression -4.0.magnitude ==>
(Double) $R5 = -4 AND
(lldb) expression (-4.0).magnitude ==>
(Double) $R6 = 4

Answer (score 3):

The reason why is because, you missed the subtle operator precedence of the expression.

In your expression:

```
-4.0.absoluteValue
```

There are two operators, - (Unary Minus Operator, prefix) and . (method operator). And it seems the precedence of . has overwhelmed -, and the expression was parsed into:

```
-(4.0.absoluteValue)
```

Therefore, you get a result of 4.0's absolute value, then flipped it with a unary minus operator, and got -4.0.

With a more in-depth look into the Swift header file, I noticed that the . (method operator) is not in the list of operators. This means . is a more fundamental operator that the language relies on, and cannot be overloaded like other ordinary operators.

I am assuming that . has a higher precedence than anything else, including + - * / =, thus leading to your confusion.

Btw, here is my solution. I made absoluteValue a method since it makes more sense than making it a property.

```
extension Double {
    func absoluteValue() -> Double {
        if self < 0 {
            return -self
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}

let myDouble: Double = -7.65
println("The absolute value of \(myDouble) is \(myDouble.absoluteValue()).")
```

Comment: One suggestion: The question is asking to add a property, not method. 

Try:


`var absoluteValue : Double {
        if(self < 0) {
            return self * -1
        }
        return self
    }
`

Answer (score 3):

Tested with Swift 4.0.2:

```
extension Double {
    var absoluteValue: Double {
        return abs(self)
    }
}

var x = -75.34
print(x.absoluteValue) // Prints 75.34
print((-31.337).absoluteValue) // Prints 31.337
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
extension Double{
    // Abs property
    var absoluteValue: Double{
        return Double.abs(self)
    }
    // Abs method
    func absValFunc() ->Double{
        return Double.abs(self)
    } }

var doubleValue = -36.00 
doubleValue.absoluteValue 
doubleValue.absValFunc()
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? In particular, please explain **how** it answers "*Does anyone know why the last line outputs -4.0 instead of 4.0?*".